# verification of compliance (Regex)

Tags: java, regex

my source

`Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher("35423523");`

`matcher.matches()` - now is false

but I need to `matcher.matches() - true` - because the string is all numbers

or for example

`Pattern.compile("[0-9A-Za-z]").matcher("35dwedwfeASADdfd423523");` - must be true

or `Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher("354ccwq23523");` - must be false
or `Pattern.compile("[0-9a-z]").matcher("354ccwq23523");` - must be true

how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex says that the string can only be one character wide, if you want more you should use [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Then it would look like this: `[0-9]+` or `[0-9A-Za-z]+`.

Comment: I don't see why that'd be necessary but explanation about anchors can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Confused `.match` with `.find()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `matches()` method checks [the entire region against the pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). That means your pattern needs to match the entire String:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher("35423523");
```

and

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9A-Za-z]+").matcher("35dwedwfeASADdfd423523");
```

From the javadocs:

> Returns true: if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher("35423523");
```

**TRUE**

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9A-Za-z]+").matcher("35dwedwfeASADdfd423523");
```

**TRUE**

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher("354ccwq23523");
```

**FALSE**

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9a-z]+").matcher("354ccwq23523");
```

**TRUE**

If you want to match certain lengths you could use `[0-9]{1, 4}` (lower limit -> upper limit)